# Google sheets, SUMIF function gives: "Argument must be a range" error if I use ADDRESS function as second parameter of range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am writing a formula in Google Sheets. Here's the formula;

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),3), C3, E$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),5), E3, F$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),6), "<>0") > 1, "MULTIPLE POSITIVE LBS THAT'S GREATER THAN ZERO", MINUS(F3, SUMIFS(G$3:G$480, C$3:C$480, C3, E$3:E$480, E3)))
```

Now the formula works like this but it only sums the values between row 3 and 480. What I want to do is get all the values between row 3 and the last non-empty field. In order to achieve that I used this formula;

```
ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A)))
```

I was able to make this formula work for `countif` function but when I use the same formula in `sumif` function, it gives me **Argument must be a range** error.

This is the second version (the one giving an error)

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(C$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),3), C3, E$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),5), E3, F$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),6), "<>0") > 1, "MULTIPLE POSITIVE LBS THAT'S GREATER THAN ZERO", MINUS(F3, SUMIFS(G$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),7), C$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),3), C3, E$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A))),5), E3)))
```

I also tried to make `ADDRESS` function work independently, in a completely different cell and it gives the correct address.

This is the first time I'm writing sheets or any kind of excel formula so I couldn't find the source of the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: ADDRESS returns a string, not a range. You'd either have to wrap that in INDIRECT or use an INDEX formula like: `C$3:INDEX(C2:C,COUNT(A2:A))` instead of `C$3:ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A)))`

Comment: C$3:INDEX(C2:C,COUNT(A2:A)) worked thanks a lot. although does it return the number of entire C column or is it the last non empty cell?

Comment: It returns a cell in column C based on how many cells in A have numbers in them.

Comment: alright got it. INDEX did the trick, formula is working now. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `ADDRESS(ROW(INDEX(A2:A,COUNT(A2:A)))` with `C$3:INDEX(C2:C,COUNT(A2:A))` did the trick. Apparently ADDRESS returns a string rather than a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Address function returns a string. Which is not accepted as an input for sumif function So you have to convert the string returned by the address function to a reference. To do this, use the indirect function.

Like so: `INDIRECT(address(2,row()-1,4,TRUE,"MAIN"))`

Now you can use this as an input to many other functions like sumif, column, row, etc.